# Replicate Directory Changes permission in AD

Tags: c#, active-directory

Anybody knows how to check whether a user has give permission to Replicate Directory Changes in Active Directory using C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check this [post](http://mosshater.blogspot.com/2010/11/check-replication-directory-changes.html) and rewrote to C#.